# AWS Kinesis long startup waiting

Tags: stream, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I'm using AWS Kinesis with spring cloud to read data from a data event hub. The deploy end with the following log:

```
2023-09-26 14:07:30.476  INFO [,,] 9331 --- [esis-consumer-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : The [ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, sequenceNumber='49644883468861416210968280224412551456184669418448486402', timestamp=null, stream='STRAM_NAME', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}, state=NEW}] has been started.
```

immediately after I try to send a message on the stream where the app is listening but the message is received at "2023-09-26 14:11:12.390".

There is more or less 4 minutes waiting. the problem is not waiting for 4 minutes but not being able to monitor the starting process.
How can I monitor the startup? How can I understand if the startup is "stuck" and the kinesis stream is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable DEBUG for `org.springframework.integration` category and there you will be able to see some logs about starting endpoints.

That's maximum how I can help from Spring perspective. Perhaps there is some time zone difference between your consumer and Kinesis server.

Comment: This is in my local environment. However I was hoping for something for production (we usually do not enable DEBUG log in production).

Comment: Yeah... Looks like our `KinesisBinderHealthIndicator` has to be improved with the info about consumers. Feel free to raise a GH issue.

Comment: Turns out there is already an Actuator endpoint for bindings to see their status: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control